# CSS header padding extends to right of window

Tags: css

I'm working on my first CSS design and I'm having an issue where the background for the header extends past the right of the header.

MWE:

```
header{
    background-color: #FF0000;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ArtStoreInitial.css"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Six+Caps" 
rel="stylesheet">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Hypothetical Art Store</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
     <h1>Hypothetical Art Store</h1>
     <h2>Super cool tagline will go here</h2>
</header>
```

If I use `display: inline;`, it breaks the header completely.

Is there a way to wrap it, give it a margin and give it padding all at the same time? Do I have to hard-code the size? That doesn't seem right.

edit:
`box-sizing` set to `border-box` or `content-box` does nothing

Comment: This may help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: Please go read [ask], and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: I've included the html, what else is needed for web-dev questions for them to be a MWE?

Comment: So you want the background of red to only cover the header?

Comment: Yes, right now it is extending to fill the screen (accounting for margins). Do I have to hard code it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the display property to `inline-block`

```css
header {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Hypothetical Art Store</h1>
  <h2>Super cool tagline will go here</h2>
</header>
```